# PHP Mail function - need assistance

Tags: php, email, mailer

I need a slight hand with getting my PHP mail function working correctly.

This is what I currently have, within the header of my php file:

```
<?php
require_once('common.php');

require_once('mailer.php');

if (isset($_POST['submitBtn']))
{
    // Get user input
    $conName  = isset($_POST['conName']) ? $_POST['conName'] : '';
    $conEmail = isset($_POST['conEmail']) ? $_POST['conEmail'] : '';
    $conPhone = isset($_POST['conPhone']) ? $_POST['conPhone'] : '';
    $conNatureof = isset($_POST['conNatureof']) ? $_POST['conNatureof'] : '';
    $conSubject = isset($_POST['conSubject']) ? $_POST['conSubject'] : '';
    $conMessage = isset($_POST['conMessage']) ? $_POST['conMessage'] : '';

    // Try to send the email
    $error = sendMail($conName,$conEmail,$conPhone,$conNatureof,$conSubject,$conMessage);
}   
?>
```

This is currently within the body of my PHP file:

```
<?php if ((!isset($_POST['submitBtn'])) || ($error != '')) {?>
 <form method="post" action="contact.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<p><label for="conName">Name:<span class="required">*</span></label><input name="conName" id="conName" type="text" class="input"/></p>
<p><label for="conEmail">Email:<span class="required">*</span></label><input name="conEmail" id="conEmail" type="text" class="input" /></p>
<p><label for="conPhone">Phone:</label><input name="conPhone" id="conPhone" type="text" class="input" /></p>
<p><label for="conNatureof">Nature of enquiry:<span class="required">*</span></label>
<select name="conNatureof" class="input" id="conNatureof">
  <option value="-">-- Please Select --</option>
  <option value="interested">Interested in joining</option>
  <option value="job">Job enquiry</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
  <option value="question">Question about membership</option>
</select></p>
<p><label for="conSubject">Subject:<span class="required">*</span></label><input name="conSubject" id="conSubject" type="text" class="input"/></p>
<p>Message:<span class="required">*</span>
<textarea name="conMessage" cols="40" rows="5" class="textarea" id="conMessage"></textarea></p>
<div class="buttonHolder">
<input class="text" type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Along with my mailer.php file having the sendMail function as this:

```
function sendMail($conName,$conEmail,$conPhone,$conNatureof,$conSubject,$conMessage)
{

//String to hold the error messages
$errorText = '';

//START VALIDATION OF USER INPUT

//Validating name
if($conName == "")
{
    $errorText = $errorText . "- Please enter a name<br />";
}



//Validating email address
//Must be a valid email address and is compulsory
if($conEmail == "")
{
    $errorText = $errorText . "- Please enter an email address<br />";
}
elseif (!filter_var($conEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
{
    $errorText = $errorText . "- Email address was invalid<br />";
}


//Validating enquiry type
if($conNatureof == "-")
{
    $errorText = $errorText . "- Please select your nature of enquiry<br />";
}

//Validating subject and message
if($conSubject == "")
{
    $errorText = $errorText . "- Please enter a subject<br />";
}

if($conMessage == "")
{
    $errorText = $errorText . "- Please enter a message<br />";
}


// If everything is OK, send the email
if ($errorText == '') 
{
    $to = "jademulholland@hotmail.com";
    $subject = $conSubject;
    $message = $conMessage;
    $from = $conEmail;
    $headers = "From:" . $conName;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}

return $errorText;
}
```

I know that most of that code is not necessary to diagnose the problem, although I thought it would be appropriate to give as much as possible.

All help is greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Please describe what is wrong, what errors do you get? Is error_reporting on?

Comment: Ok so I see loads of code, but no idea what the issue is

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad. No, I do not have error_reporting turned on.
basically, no email is coming to my email address and I am not to sure why. Very new to PHP and have never used the mail function before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are developing contact form with validation . please follow the link you will get idea else google it [contact form with validation](http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/php/php-form-validation.php)

else 
google it [try in google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=contact%20form%20php%20with%20validation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-beta&gws_rd=cr)

Comment: Mate, thats fantastic. Exactly what I needed. Your help was greatly appreciated :)

Comment: its ok , get ride on php . its fantastic